# How to define a multi key index when the the find()-Request contains a comparison

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I do:

```
const reassigns = await OoOEvents.find({
    event: 'REASSIGN', // ... reassigns
    accountId,         // ... of the assignee
    clientKey,         // ... in this company
    _id: {             // ... executed after
        $gte: objectIdWithTimestamp(startDate.unix())
    }
}).toArray();
```

Searching for entries after a specific date.

Is it helpful to define an index on the first three keys `( event, accountId, clientKey )`?

Or how else can I speed up the `find()`?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#create-a-compound-index

Comment: Yes. That's what I was searching for. If you think it makes sense, answer this and I can accept. Otherwise, I will close it.

Comment: Glad it helped but it would be better to delete the question really.